# Jquery fancybox 2.1.3 vimeo issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox, vimeo, fancybox-2

I have implements jquery fancybox 2.1.3 on here : http://n2lose.kodingen.com/homepage/test.html

source

```
<a href="http://vimeo.com/35400388" class="Video pull-left">
                <img src="background/Video.png" alt="video platform" />
            </a>
```

script:

```
$('.Video').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            helpers : {
                media : {}
            }
        });
```

I follow the examples on here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples to do that.
I don't know why it doesn't work and see the console firebug the error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Anybody can help me plz?

Comment: why have you deleted the comments ?... I pointed out before that you had to upgrade your files. Comments can be useful for other people making the same mistake like you.

Comment: @JFK, I've tagged the comments as obsolete to have them removed, as the version of fancybox wasn't the issue (Although it's now ironic that the OP has mixed the old fancybox with the newer fancybox). The issue when using the older fancybox or even the newer v2.1.3 is the requirement of Fancybox Media Helper file v1.05. It's too bad the Fancybox website doesn't provide that info, as one needs to dig into the source just to find out. Cheers!

Comment: @arttronics : I think it's not your call to remove other people's comments ... you can comment over if you disagree with something though. "Ironically" the OP had always loaded the Fancybox Media Helper file in the sample page he posted (it was the first thing I checked) and "ironically" I asked him to upgrade his fancybox files, which "ironically" was your **Website final solution** ... BTW : flag comments when they are inappropriate or offensive but not "obsolete" (don't play the smart guy).

Comment: A moderator removed those comments. When I started I noticed the OPs site has the new JS for FB, but also noticed no FB Media Helper file. I then created an Answer for that with jsFiddle. The OP was also online & accepted my answer after that file was used! The OP then wanted clues on how to fix a new problem: Misalignment of the FB Video. The ironic part: I discovered after the OP signed off that "somebody" forgot to tell him to update the .css file too! In fact, the Final Solution you speak of was added after my accepted answer, while he was away, to prevent him from making a new SO Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO: Fancybox v2.1.3**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5zXV/2/)

That example at the Fancybox webpage requires the use of an additional .js file found at this location:

```
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js
```

You should also define a `width` and a `height` for the video to be presented in, such as  `1280 x 656`. To know what exact video dimensions to use, in order to preserve **Aspect Ratio** of the video (so black bars are not shown at top/bottom or sides), just click the Download Button at the Vimeo webpage of that video.

**EDIT:** Also, I found this [**iframed jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9HH5/) as well.